# Python using Selenium, ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am webscraping http://m.imdb.com/feature/bornondate I think my code was working before but today it is giving me the error:

> "ValueError: too many values to unpack" at File
>   "/Users/Desktop/IMDB_BornToday_Scraping.py", line 28, in 
>       profession, bestWork = person.split(", ")

(The page changes daily) What is the issue here?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv

c = csv.writer(open("celebritiesBornToday.csv", "wb"))
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/Users/Downloads/phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx/bin/phantomjs')
driver.get("http://m.imdb.com/feature/bornondate")

# waiting for posters to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
posters = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section.posters")))

#giving headings to the columns of the csv file
c.writerow(['name','image','profession','bestWork'])

# extracting the data poster by poster
for a in posters.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.poster'):

    # Fetching the picture of the celebrity
    image = a.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src').split('._V1.')[0] + '._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg'
    # Fetching the profession and bestWork of the celebrity as person
    person = a.find_element_by_css_selector('div.detail').text
    # Splitting person into profession and bestWork
    profession, bestWork = person.split(",")
    # Fetching the name of the celebrity
    name = a.find_element_by_css_selector('span.title').text

    #Printing the Name of the Celebrity
    print "Name of the celebrity: "+name
    #Printing the Image of the Celebrity
    print "Image: "+image
    #Printing the Profession of the Celebrity
    print "Profession: "+profession
    #Printing the BestWork of the Celebrity
    print "BestWork: "+bestWork

    #saving the name, image, profession, bestWork of the celebrity into a csv file
    c.writerow([name,image,profession,bestWork])
```

Comment: Working for me, interesting.

Comment: Should I just restart?

Comment: Could you provide the complete output you get? Thanks.

Comment: MacBook-Pro:~ MacBook$ python /Users/MacBook/Desktop/IMDB_BornToday_Scraping.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MacBook/Desktop/IMDB_BornToday_Scraping.py", line 28, in <module>
    profession, bestWork = person.split(",")
ValueError: too many values to unpack
MacBook-Pro:~ MacBook$

Comment: So, it is basically failing on the first person. Could you check what is printed: `print driver.find_element_by_css_selector('section.posters h1').text`?

Comment: Oh its printing March 16 :( I think the webpage changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first person's, born on March 16, best work title contains a comma:

```
Actor, "I, Robot"
```

Which leads to a `ValueError` while the split on it is unpacked, demo:

```
>>> s = 'Actor, "I, Robot"'
>>> profession, bestWork = s.split(',')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

You need to **split by the first occurrence of comma**:

```
profession, bestWork = person.split(",", 1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> profession, bestWork = s.split(',', 1)
>>> profession
'Actor'
>>> bestWork
' "I, Robot"'
```